# Set up emacs server so that it dies when the last frame is closed

Tags: emacs, daemon, kill, emacsclient

I have run into issues using the emacs server started when I log in and emacsclient.  Specifically, I use the same emacs server for different R projects things get ugly and commands from different projects end up going to the same R session.

My work around is to invoke a second server with `/usr/bin/emacs --daemon=Rmd-1` when I log in. I have a bash script written such that the first `.Rmd` file I work with attaches to this daemon and then the command `/usr/bin/emacs --daemon=Rmd-2` is issued. If I end up working with a second `.Rmd` file, then this server is used and a third server is started with `/usr/bin/emacs --daemon=Rmd-3` and ready to work with another `.Rmd` file if needed.

This works pretty well except for one thing.  Because after many years I am hard wired to end my emacs session using `C-x C-c` by the end of the day I have many emacs servers running.  I'm looking for a way to trigger `save-buffers-kill-emacs` when the `C-x C-c` command is given in an emacsclient running on a daemon matching "Rmd-[0-9]+".  I can't see any `emacsclient` options that would do that and I'm at a loss as to how to edit my `custom.el` file.

Can some one help me?

(note I'm running GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.30) on Ubuntu 22.04)

Comment: Why not just rebind C-x C-c to save-buffers-kill-emacs? `(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-c") 'save-buffers-kill-emacs)`

Comment: That's 50% of the solution, I need to set it up so it only uses the remapping if the for the session "daemon==R-md-[0-9]+".   Any suggestions or hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Drawing on [McNisse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1945467/mcnisse)'s suggestion, adding the following to my `personal.el` file seems to give me the desired behavior.

```
;; Remap C-c C-x if daemon name matches "Rmd-[0-9]+"
;;  
(cond
 ((string-prefix-p "Rmd-" (daemonp))
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-c") 'save-buffers-kill-emacs)
  )
 )
```